# fill this array with another arrays elements with genetic algorithm in pyevolve

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

for example:

```
a=1500
b=[500,400,200]
```

One answer is:

```
ans=[1,2,1]
```

because `1*500+2*400+1*200=1500` I want to write a program with genetic algorithm with best evaluation function to solve this problem with this array with pyevolve python evolutionary tool.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the coefficients in the answer must be integers, what you're describing is a [linear Diophantine equation](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/number-theory/linear-diophantine/linear-diophantine.html). It's not a good fit for a genetic algorithm, as the solution space is neither continuous nor smooth. (That is, there is not always a possible input between any two other inputs, and the "correct" answer will not necessarily be anywhere near other nearly-correct inputs.)

(If the coefficients in the answer can be real numbers, finding a solution is trivial to the point that a genetic algorithm would be overkill.)